# Donde encuentro la carpeta para acceder al emulador de AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio

Necesito acceder al directorio que en `ubuntu` es `/Sdk/platform-tools`.

Ahora estoy en windows y el directorio no es el mismo, lo necesito para poder acceder mediante la terminal a una base de datos que he creado en android-studio.

Para luego acceder a la carpeta que tengo en el device explorer abierta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He avanzado algo, he llegado hasta aquí:

`C:\Users\tonij\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools` pero aún me queda ejecutar

el dispositivo

Gracias!

Comment: He avanzado algo, he llegado hasta aquí: C:\Users\tonij\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools pero aún me queda ejcutar el dispositivo

Comment: Debes entrar al directorio /emulators y ahí iniciar el emulador especificando tu AVD (si no tienes debes crear uno) e iniciarlo : emulator -avd "<Nombre AVD>"

Answer (score 1):

Primero revisa cual es la ubicación de tu Android SDK

`File` > `Settings` > `Appareance & Behavior` > `Android SDK`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de esa dirección puedes ubicar ahora el directorio `/platform-tools`, pero si deseas abrir la ubicación de los emuladores, esta se encuentra en el directorio `/emulator` dentro de la ubicación de tu SDK.

Si deseas ejecutar el emulador, realizalo desde este directorio, suponiendo tienes un Android Virtual Device (AVD) llamado "Pixel 2", puedes iniciarlo de esta forma:

```
>emulator -avd "Pixel 2"
```

o también:

```
>emulator @"Pixel 2"
```

Revisa más información : 
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline

Answer (score 1):

Para acceder a los archivos del emulador, desde la máquina host en Windows, depende de como tengas configurado Android Studio.

En mi caso el emulador lo tengo en la siguiente dirección:

C:\Users"user_name"\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio"version"\device-explorer"emulator_name" [emulator-5554]

Para que en este directorio te aparezcan los archivos, por ejemplo el de la bbdd tienes que abrirlo desde "Device Explorer":

[image: Device Explorer]

y te aparecerá en el subdirectorio:
...[emulator-5554]\data\data\proyect_work_space\databases

Una ver lo tengas ya podrías usarlo con una aplicación para ver el estado de la bbdd.

Nota: Si el proyecto lo tienes definido para usar una API igual o superior a la 26, puedes usar la herramienta "App Inspection:

[image: App Inspection]

Answer (score 0):

Es este icono:

[image]

Luego presionas <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> y escribes **taskmgr**, y *Click derecho* en el emulador, *Abrir la ubicación del archivo* y ahí la tienes.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer]. En esta pregutna  se refiere en la pregunta a la carpeta física no a como abrir el emulador.

Comment: pero desde el taskmgr puedes darle a abrir ubicacion del archivo

Answer (score 0):

1. Para saber donde esta guardado algún emulador tienes que hacer click en el icono de Device Manager, esta barra de iconos se encuentra en el lado superior derecho justo debajo de los botones de minimizar, agrandar y cerrar.

[image: Icono Device Manager]

2. Después te abrirá una ventana al costado derecho mostrándote los dispositivos que tienes instalados, ahí tendrás que localizar el dispositivo que te interesa y dar click en la ultima flecha, la que apunta hacia abajo.

[image: Ventana Device Manager]

3. Te desplegara un menú y ahí tendrás que dar en show on disk y te abrira una explorador con la ruta en donde se encuentra el emulador. Tambien puedes hacer el paso 1 dando click en Tools/Device Manager, desde el menú superior izquierdo.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que respondo tarde pero espero le sirva a alguien mas (:D).